# How to extend OctoberCMS plugin to send Slack notifications?

Tags: laravel, octobercms, octobercms-plugins

I want to extend [Magic Forms](https://octobercms.com/plugin/martin-forms) plugin to send Slack notifications at the same time with mail notification but I don't know if it is possible.

For my own plugin I'm using [Slack for PHP](https://github.com/maknz/slack) library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I Guess you can, Just use composer for plugin add your package to plugin using composer.

then read this document https://skydiver.github.io/october-plugin-forms/docs/advanced/events/#docsNav

> you need to use add `Event Listeners` and fire up your notification

```php
public function boot() {

    # Listen for Record after saved
    Event::listen('martin.forms.afterSaveRecord', function (&$formdata, $component) {
        // here use your slack lib and send notification
        // $formData has all data
    });

}
```

if any doubts please comment.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I need.